# OpenGL issue: 'incompatible' vs 'cannot find'

Tags: c, opengl, gcc, makefile, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying [a program](https://github.com/Golevka/deformation-transfer) about blender deformation. My laptop is amd64 and able to support i386.

```
faye@fish:/usr/bin$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
faye@fish:/usr/bin$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

I have no much experience about makefile script. According to the google search info, I made two line code additions in the makefile.mk.

```
# -I option to help the compiler finding the headers
CFLAGS += $(addprefix  -I, $(INCLUDE_PATH))
CC=gcc -m32
```

Here is the issue: 
When I run any template OpenGL code with:

```
gcc test.c -lm -lpthread -lglut -lGL -lGLU -o test
```

It seems the code and the libs work correctly.

However, if I do the same to the makefile.mk(CC=gcc), it gives many errors in the following form:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `../external/lib/libxxxxxxxx.a(xxxxxxxx.o)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

if I use (CC = gcc -m32), the error will switch to:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLU
```

I guess maybe there is something wrong in 64 bit os running 32 bit application and libs linking?

Answer (score 2):

`-m32`, when used with a x86-64 compiler does not mean "compile this program for i386", but actually means "create a program for x86-64 CPUs using only instructions that operate on 32 bit registers".

What you have there is some binary that has been compiled for native i386 and now try to combine it with a program that's compile for x86-64 with just 32 bit registers. Those two don't fit together. The big question here of course is, why do you want to use those i386 binaries at all. There are some good reasons for using 32bit-x86-64 (half the size for pointers and which can massively reduce the memory bandwidth), but in general you want 64 bit binaries. So many problems of 32 bit memory management vanish by virtue of having vast amounts of address space.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `extenal/lib` is full of 32 bit precompiled archives. You *could* track each one down and recompile (or use shared libraries), but that'll be a massive PITA.

Just because your OS supports i386 doesn't mean you've got the libraries installed. In this case of that program, it's enough to install `libc6-dev-i386` and `freeglut3-dev:i386` packages.

PS: No need to edit anything. `make CC='gcc -m32'`